# Make links in SocialEngine

Tags: zend-framework, socialengine

this is quite simple i guess, but i cannot find a nice API codex for SocialEngine and APIs files in installation folders are a bit messy…

i would like to create a link to a page (say "/foo") obviously with baseurl.

in tpl files i can do *$this->baseUrl('foo')*, but it doens't work on **Controller.php**. I've got that controllers call APIs with *Engine_Api::_()* path, i.e. i called viewer user fullname with *$this->viewer()* in .tpl and *Engine_Api::_()->user()->getViewer()* in Controller.php, but i cannot find anywhere the class to call baseUrl() method.

Any help here? ^^ I'd really appreciate if anyone has a API codex link for SE4 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->view->baseUrl('foo')`